# how do I use overlays in d7?

Tags: 7, modal-dialogs

Does Drupal 7 have built-in functionality for using jquery overlays? I would like to do some confirmation screens and form-wizard type stuff with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked: [How to Add a jQuery UI Dialog to Drupal 7](http://dansilvercentral.com/tutorial-add-jquery-ui-popup-drupal-7)?

There is also [Drupal 7 jQuery (Popup e ui.dialog)](http://ganovelli.it/creare-un-popup-drupal-7-con-librerie-jquery-ui-dialog), in Italian.

Comment: The "How to Add a jQuery UI Dialog to Drupal 7" was very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use jQuery tools.

http://flowplayer.org/tools/

Integrating with Drupal is just a matter of adding a line to your theme.info file, i.e.

`scripts[] = js/jquery-tools1.42/jquery.tools.min.js`